# How do I add a foreign key to Identity user in EF Core?

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Let's say I have a `Todo` model with a corresponding `Todo` table (`DbSet<Todo>`) in an EF-generated database. The table will store a todo item per row. Each user (in an ASP.NET Core Identity + IdentityServer app) will be associated with multiple todo items (one-to-many, a user can have multiple todo items).

The way I'd do it is to add a `UserId` foreign key to the `Todo` model that represents the user that owns the todo item .

How would I do that with EF Core while utilizing the classes proved by ASP.NET Core Identity? My intuition was to add the following to the `Todo` class model:

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

This uses `ApplicationUser` (the ASP.NET Core Identity default user class model) as discovery to populate `UserId` with a foreign key.

Here's the problem: when I run `Update-Database` I get an error! It says `The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.`.

Browsing through the code for `IdentityUserLogin`, I can see it has a property `UserId` which should be considered a primary key, right?

Anyway, to make sure its registered as a primary key, I added this code to `ApplicationUser`'s `OnModelCreating` method: `builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(u => u.Id);`. I still get the same error! Not sure what I'm doing wrong here :(. Edit: Yes, I called the base class so that's not the problem.

Note: I know I can add a field to each user that carries a collection of todo item Ids instead of having a foreign key, but I'm not sure if that's the good way of doing this. Guidance on this issue appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't shared the code for this, but I'm guessing you have made an override of `OnModelCreating` in your db context, but have not called `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);`.

Without the base call, your context isn't applying the Identity related schema.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Add Identity related model configuration
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Your fluent modeling here
}
```

---

**Edit: Felt like giving this a whirl so I just performed the below tasks.  The TLDR would be that it worked out for me.  I believe the issue you are having has nothing to do with the key you are making and something unrelated is causing your failure, because the failure you are getting is on a completely different table than the one you are building schema for.**

I created a new .net core web application using Identity.  First thing I did was call update-database to build up the DB from the initial migration that the project came with.  This worked.

Next I added a Todo class. No properties, just an Id and the User field.  Didn't even mark the foreign key.

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I added it to the ApplicationDbContext as a DbSet.  Only alteration to the context was to add the ToDo DbSet

Then I called `add-migration todo` in the package manager console to build the todo migration.  It generated as expected with the FK in place.

```
public partial class Todo : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Todos",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Todos", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Todos_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Todos_UserId",
            table: "Todos",
            column: "UserId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Todos");
    }
}
```

I then added some code to my About controller action to just stick a record into the table to make sure the FK was working.  It was.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> About()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    var todo = new Todo
    {
        User = user
    };
    _context.Todos.Add(todo);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return View();
}
```

Screenshot of the record in the DB along with tables and keys: 
[image]

Other than the obvious that you have more fields on your Todo class is there something drastically different that you've done differently that may lead us to the problem?

Comment: Nope, that's exactly how I did it. In fact the override was already there in the code generated by ASP.NET Core Identity so I just added my Fluent API below the `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` line. Still getting those errors!

Comment: @Biarity hrm. The AspNetUserLogins is a different table from AspNetUsers which is why your key had no effect.  Something must be getting in the way of the normal build up of tables.

Comment: Shouldn't it work without me having to even use Fluent API? Why can't it just infer the primary key of ApplicationUser when I use it as discovery in the foreign key tag? Maybe I'm missing something (ie. is this the correct way of doing one-to-many in EF anyway)?

Comment: Yes it should.  I just updated with some tests I ran, but sadly everything just worked.  I don't think the key you are adding has anything to do with the error you are getting.  The key you are adding is against the AspNetUsers table, but it is the AspNetUserLogins table that is throwing errors.  My hunch is that something else is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the extended edit. I did the exact same thing and got the error, seems like a VS2017 RC2 + EF Core 1.1.0 bug, submitted an issue on GitHub about it.

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same problem as @Biarity

Comment: VS 2017R2 could be the factor.  I was using VS 2015 Community.  Were you also using 2017R2 akousmata?

Comment: @DavevanHerten nope, this is in 2015 community.  Although, I realized after my comment that I'm trying to do this across a different `DbContext` for the class I'm using which needs the foreign key into Application User.  I have a `PeopleContext` that I'm trying to define which has a `Person` class.  `Person` has an `ApplicationUser`.  I'll try it from within the _same_ context and see what happens

Comment: Ok, I see what the issue was in my example.  When I moved all of my classes that i wanted to foreignkey into the `ApplicationUser` into the `ApplicationDbContext` it worked fine.  I think the reverse would also be true (i.e. using an `ApplicationUser` DbSet within my `PeopleContext`) but now that i have it working, I'm not going to mess with it.

Comment: For EF Core I used `IdentityUser` instead of `ApplicationUser`

Comment: How could you achieve it with two DbContext ? One for IdentityDbContext and another for the ApplicationDbContext ?

Answer (score 3):

Dave, your solution worked fine !

Just some details for readers, adding the class to ApplicationDbContext as a DbSet means adding to the file ApplicationDbContext.cs Something like :

```
public DbSet<MyClass> MyClass { get; set; }
```

and when it's needed (in Package Manager Console) :
PM> Add-Migration MyClass
PM> Update-Database