# Duplicate table created when adding IdentityUser as foreign key in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am using PostgreSql as my DB. I am trying to add a foreign key to the user's table but instead of that a duplicate `IdentityUser` table is being created.

I have inherited `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` for `ApplicationDbContext` whose code is:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

This is able to create all the tables as:

[image]

I am trying to create a model where the user is the foreign key by doing:

```cs
public class AccountModel
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public BankModel BankDetails { get; set; }

    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}
```

And it's DBContext is

```cs
public class AccountDbContext: DbContext
{
    public AccountDbContext(DbContextOptions<AccountDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BankModel> Banks { get; set; }
}
```

Looking at the post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41275590/3782963, the accepted answer uses `ApplicationUser` which I believe is similar to `IdentityUser`, when I do the migrations, instead of adding an FK to `AspNetUsers` it creates a new table called `IdentityUser` and then an FK is added to this newly created table. Which looks like:

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Help!

**Update**

I tried this code with Azure SQL Server too and it still gave me the same problem. Also, I added `[ForeignKey("AspNetUser")]`

```cs
public class AccountModel
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public BankModel BankDetails { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AspNetUsers")]
    public IdentityUser User { get; set; }
}
```

I still get the same problem.

---

**Update 2**

The relationship is between two different contexts, i.e. `ApplicationDbContext` and `AccountDbContext`. Adding `public DbSet<AccountModel> Accounts { get; set; }` to `ApplicationDbContext` works fine and automatically adds an FK relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the relationship between `AccountModel` and `IdentityUser` in your model builder.

Something along the lines of

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<AccountModel>()
            .HasOne(accountModel=> accountModel.User);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

See here for info on [single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1) and foreign keys.

Comment: the docs have some good examples on keys, navigation properties, shadow properties ect. I recommend you have a a play and run a few migrations to see what you end up with. Getting a good grasp on these concepts right now will save you heaps later.

Comment: I will have a look at the docs. But there is no change in the table creation, I still have a duplicate table and Account table pointing to IdentityUser table

Comment: Take a look at the Foreign Key samples. You have your models now your just trying to configure the model builder correctly to define the relationships. I have not done EF code first for a bit but i remember it took me a bit of trial and error to get the end result i wanted.

Comment: try this syntax. 

`builder.Entity<AccountModel>().HasOne<IdentityUser>(accountModel=> accountModel.User).WithMany();`

Comment: No still the same issue. For some reason, it still creates `IdentityUser` table. Not sure why it is not using `AspNetUser` table. I will give it a go +1 for help.