# I want the UserId column in my Job table to reference the Id column in the AspNetUser table (ASP.NET Core Identity)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have created tables using ASP.NET Core Identity. I need to refer my `AspNetUser` table to my `Job` table. I have created a `CustomIdentity` class which inherits from `IdentityUser` for adding extra columns in my ASPNetUser table.

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace InventoryManagement.Models
{
    public class CustomIdentity :IdentityUser
    {
        public string  IsEngineer { get; set; }
        public string  authpassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my `DbContext` class for `IdentityDbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace InventoryManagement.Models.Data
{
    public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomIdentity>
    {
        public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options) :base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

`ASPNETUser` table got created and I am able to insert values into it using `UserManager` to register users. I need to refer this user in my Job table. And here is my code for `Jobdbcontext` where I declare all my other tables:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace InventoryManagement.Models.Data
{
    public class JobDBcontext : DbContext
    {
       public JobDBcontext(DbContextOptions<JobDBcontext> options) : base(options) 
       {
       }

       public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
       public DbSet<JobType> Jobtype { get; set; }
       public DbSet<ManufacturingBay> Manufacturingbay { get; set; }
       public DbSet<ProjectCategory> Projectcategory { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Currency> Currency { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Category> ItemCategory { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Budget> ItemBudget { get; set; }
       public DbSet<SubCategory> ItemSubcategory { get; set; }
       public DbSet<ItemMaster> ItemMaster { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Bom> Bom { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
       public DbSet<UOM> UomMaster { get; set; }
       public DbSet<PR> PR { get; set; }
       public DbSet<PRDetails> PRDetails { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Purchase> Purchase { get; set; }
       public DbSet<PurchaseDetails> PurchaseDetails { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
            if (modelBuilder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));
            }

            modelBuilder.Entity<JobType>().HasKey(jt => jt.Jobtypeid);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectCategory>().HasKey(jt => jt.Pid);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasKey(jt => jt.cid);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Bom>().HasKey(jt => jt.BID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Budget>()
                        .HasKey(b => b.ID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasKey(c => c.CategoryId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SubCategory>()
                .HasKey(s => s.SubCategoryId);
             modelBuilder.Entity<ItemMaster>()
                .HasKey(i => i.itemid);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UOM>()
              .HasKey(i => i.uid);
            // Configure relationships
            modelBuilder.Entity<Budget>()
          .HasMany(b => b.categories)
          .WithOne(c => c.Budget)
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasMany(c => c.SubCategories)
                .WithOne(i => i.category)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            //  modelBuilder.Entity<SubCategory>()
            //      .HasMany(s => s.ItemMasters)
            //      .WithOne(i => i.subcategory)
            //      .HasForeignKey(i => i.category)
            //      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            // Other configurations for your entity can go here

            //modelBuilder.Entity<PR>()
            //              .HasKey(p => p.Prid);

            //modelBuilder.Entity<PRDetails>()
            //    .HasKey(d => d.Prtblid);

            //modelBuilder.Entity<PRDetails>()
            //    .Property(d => d.Prid);  // Ensure Prid property is properly configured, adjust as needed

            //modelBuilder.Entity<PRDetails>()
            //    .HasOne(d => d.PR)
            //    .WithMany(p => p.PRDetails)
            //    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Prid)
            //    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // or specify other actions as needed

            // Additional configurations for other entities and relationships

            modelBuilder.Entity<PR>()
              .HasKey(p => p.Prid);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PRDetails>()
                .HasKey(d => d.PrDetailId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PRDetails>()
                .HasOne(d => d.PR)
                .WithMany(p => p.PRDetails)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Prid)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); // Change this to NoAction or other options

            modelBuilder.Entity<PRDetails>()
                .HasOne(d => d.Bom)
                .WithMany() // Assuming Bom doesn't have a navigation property back to PRDetails
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Bomid)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Purchase>()
             .HasKey(p => p.POID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseDetails>()
                .HasKey(d => d.potblid);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseDetails>()
                .HasOne(d => d.Purchase)
                .WithMany(p => p.PurchaseDetails)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.POID)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); // Change this to NoAction or other options

            modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseDetails>()
                .HasOne(d => d.prdetails)
                .WithMany() // Assuming Bom doesn't have a navigation property back to PRDetails
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PrDetailId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
           .HasOne(j => j.User)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(j => j.UserId)
           .IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Job` model where I am referencing my CustomIdentity.

```
namespace InventoryManagement.Models
{
    public class Job
    {
        public int Jobsequenceno { get; set; }
        public int JobId { get; set; }

        public string JobName { get; set; } 
  
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public DateTime JobDate { get; set; }
        public JobType JobType { get; set; }

        public ManufacturingBay ManufacturingBay { get; set; }
        public ProjectCategory Projectcategory { get; set; }
        public Currency currency { get; set; }
        public Double JobRate { get; set; }
        public Double Ordervalue { get; set; }
        public Double Ordervalueinbasecurrency { get; set; }

        public string  JobDescription { get; set; }
        public string Paymentterms { get; set; }
        public string Deliveryterms { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public CustomIdentity User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Upon running migrations of 2 `DbContext` tables are created ..but upon running migration of JobDBcontext another class called customidentity is created which has exactly same column like my ASPNetUser and my job table is referring to that class.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Jobs] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Jobs_CustomIdentity_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CustomIdentity] ([Id])
        ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I want the Job  table to refer to the `ASPNETUSER` table which is having value instead of this CustomIdentity table.... I am able to insert user data to Job table.but upon listing job I am referring to `CustomIdentity` which is showing null..

```
 [HttpGet("List")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> List()
 {
     // use dbContext to read the tags
     var Joblist = await jobdbcontext.Jobs
                                     .Include(j => j.Customer)
                                     .Include(j => j.JobType)
                                     .Include(j => j.ManufacturingBay)
                                     .Include(j => j.Projectcategory)
                                     .Include(j => j.CustomIdentity)
                                     .Include(j => j.currency)
                                     .Include(j => j.User)
                                     .ToListAsync();

     return View(Joblist);
 }
```

How to resolve this? So that my `Job` table will refer to the `ASPNetUser` table which has the value instead of `CustomIdentity` table. The `CustomIdentity` model is created to add extra columns in my `ASPNetUser` table.

I am new to this... can anyone help with this?

Comment: Someone marked it as irrelevant or not clear ...but i am facing trouble in creating the relationship between job table and ASPnetuser table. it would  be great if someone could help me.

Comment: I do something similar by specifying the relationship in the model configuration. Here's an example for a Person entity referencing my custom ApplicationUser:
            entity.HasOne(d => d.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(p => p.People)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Email)
                .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Email)
                .IsRequired(false);

Comment: Have you try to add `public virtual ICollection<Job> Job { get; set; }` in your CustomIdentity model ?

Comment: relationship is maintained between Job and CustomIdentity table  ..one  more table same like ASPNetUser is created automatically .I want the my Job table to refer ASPNetUser table. And the user data resides in ASPNetUser table.                                                    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Jobs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Jobs_CustomIdentity_customIdentityId] FOREIGN KEY([customIdentityId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CustomIdentity] ([Id]) is created on migration.                                            CustomIdentity table has no data in it. It has the same structure as ASPNetUser

Comment: I am facing the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942405/duplicate-table-created-when-adding-identityuser-as-foreign-key-in-asp-net-core